# ADOX - tables in an SQL Server Schema not listed

Tags: sql-server, adox

I am retrieving table names using ADOX, but any tables that are within a schema other than DBO are not listed.

```
Sub ListTablesADOX()
  Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection

  'Open connection you want To get database objects
  Conn.Provider = "MSDASQL"
  Conn.Open "DSN=...;Database=...;", "UID", "PWD"

  'Create catalog object
  Dim Catalog As New ADOX.Catalog
  Set Catalog.ActiveConnection = Conn

  'List tables And columns
  Dim Table As ADOX.Table
  For Each Table In Catalog.Tables
      Debug.Print Table.Name
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please try to connect with `Conn.Open ("Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Data Source=<servername>;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=<dbname>")`. (or use other provider than SQLNCLI10.1). Maybe it's provider-specific issue? Or it'll behave differently with SSPI...

Comment: Thanks, but it seems no matter how I connect, only objects in the default (dbo) schema are listed.  Are you able to see objects in other schema's?

Comment: Yes, with above method it lists all schemas I see with Management Studio.

Comment: Ah, so if you create a new schema and move a table into that schema, the table is still listed using the above code?

Comment: Looking at ado method OpenSchema, that looks like i can specify a schema name.

Answer (score 1):

I dropped using ADOX, re-coded all my get catalog info procedures using ADO OpenSchema methods instead, I couldn't get ADOX to anything beyond the dbo schema.